# The Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

following is my code where I am declaring a column as private string and I am using the value to bind the value to grid but I am getting the error the input string was not in correct format near "PolicyRenewalGracePeriodDays "..please see the highlighted text below and advise me please

```
/// </summary>
private const string COL_UNDERWRITER_DISPLAY_NAME = "UnderwriterDisplayName";
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private const string COL_UNDERWRITER_INITIALS = "UnderwriterInitials";
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private const string COL_UA_DISPLAY_NAME = "UADisplayName";
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private const string COL_UA_INITIALS = "UA";
**private const string COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS = "PolicyRenewalGracePeriodDays";**
#endregion


    protected void grdAction_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UltraGridRow row in this.grdAction.DisplayLayout.Rows)
            {
                TemplatedColumn col;
                CellItem item;
                HyperLink docLink;
                HyperLink letterLink;
                HyperLink actionLink;
                Label actionLabel;
                var policyClassId = Utility.GetCurrentPolicyClassId();
             PolicyClass policyClass = Utility.GetCurrentPolicyClassEntity();
                var accountId = (int) row.DataKey;
                var insuredName = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_INSURED_NAME_HIDDEN).Text;
                var referenceNumber = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_REFERENCE_NUMBER).Text;
                var statusId = int.Parse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_STATUS_ID).Text);

                var optionNames = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_OPTION_NAMES).Text))
                    optionNames = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_OPTION_NAMES).Text;

                var optionCount = int.Parse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_OPTION_COUNT).Text);
                var isVoidable = (row.Cells.FromKey(COL_IS_VOIDABLE).Text == "1");
                bool renewalFlag;
                bool doNotRenewFlag;
                bool hasRenewingReferenceNumber;
                var currentUser = (User) Session[AppConstants.SK_CURRENT_USER];
                var expirationDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                bool convertedFlag;
                var documentCount = int.Parse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_DOCUMENT_COUNT).Text);
                var allowAddLayer = bool.Parse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_ALLOW_ADD_LAYER).Text);
                var renewableLayers = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWABLE_LAYERS).Text;
                int renewalGracePeriodDays = 0;

                **renewalGracePeriodDays = int.Parse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text);**
```

Comment: My guess `row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text` contains chars other then `0-9` :)

Comment: You need to identify the value of `row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text` at the time the exception occurs.  Then update your question to include that value.

Comment: `int.Parse("thisIsNotAValidNumber")` will throw an exception like the one you see. Check what the text string is. It is probably empty or containing letters or something.

Comment: `int.TryParse` is not a solution as said in below answers. The problem you should think about is why this field contains chars that are not valid.

Comment: how is the "PolicyRenewalGracePeriodDays" column set up in the grid?  What properties have you set on that column and any editor that you may be using for that column?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely `row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text` is not returning what you expect. If it has anything other than 0-9 or value larger than `int.MaxValue` you'll get an exception. Additionally `null` or `System.String.Empty` will cause an exception.

You can use `TryParse` instead which will return a bool indicating whether or not the parse worked. If it works, the int you pass in will be set to the string you pass in.

To give some actual code;

```
if(!int.TryParse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text, out renewalGracePeriodDays))
         renewalGracePeriod = MyDefaultValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am trying to use the code which you provided me and Its says that it has some invalid arguments..Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1567194 One of my variable names was wrong. I just fixed it. Can't think of anything else... Those are the args specified on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What happen if the cell doesn't contain a valid number (for example an empty string)?.
You get the exception mentioned in your question.
A simple workaround is to use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method

```
int renewalGracePeriodDays;
string temp = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text;
Int32.TryParse(temp, out renewalGracePeriodDays);
```

From the MSDN docs

> When this method returns, *[the second parameter]* contains the 32-bit signed integer value
>   equivalent to the number contained in s *[the first parameter]*, if the conversion succeeded,
>   or **zero if the conversion failed**. The conversion fails if the s
>   parameter is null, is not of the correct format, or represents a
>   number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is
>   passed uninitialized

Bold and text in square brakets have been added by me. So if your default value should be zero you don't have to do any test on the result of the TryParse method.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the above answers, you can easily create a little extension method to handle these cases gracefully:

```
public static class ExtensionUtils
{
    public static int ToZeroIfNotInt(this string valueToConvert)
    {
        int number =0;
        int.TryParse(valueToConvert,out number);
        return number;
    }
}
```

And then call it as so:

```
renewalGracePeriodDays = row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text.ToZeroIfNotInt();
```

Comment: What if some values are really `0` some has invalid chars?

Comment: @L.B. It will still return the value correctly. It will simply default it to `0` if the value cannot be parsed. You can probably add a parameter to the extension method to pick a default value other than 0. For example, you may want to return -1 instead, to indicate a non-valid value...

Comment: Icarus, suppose that the field contains the integer as hex string. you will return 0 for 1a, also 0 for 0. The real problem is why OP gets this message not how it can be supressed.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the column you are checking is either an empty string, or contains non-integer data. I recommend using the TryParse method.

```
int renewalGracePeriodDays;
if (!int.TryParse(row.Cells.FromKey(COL_RENEWAL_GRACE_PERIOD_DAYS).Text), out renewalGracePeriodDays)
{
    renewalGracePeriodDays = 0;
    // Inside here, you can log the exception, alert the user, or end processing
}
```

If the TryParse fails, your grace period will default to 0. It's a good idea to use this method when dealing with user inputs, because there's no telling what people will enter, even when properly prompted...

Comment: And Evan beat me to it. Rats.